# Detecting a nonrepeating decimal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

For two numbers $x$ and $y$, both rational numbers, how can we detect if $\frac xy$ is going to be non-terminating, non-repeating decimal?

Comment: if $y\neq 0$ then $\frac xy$ is rational too so decimals will repeat.

Comment: @zwim  or terminate, as in the case $\dfrac{\,\frac16\,}{\,\frac23\,}=0.25$

Comment: @Henry Some people consider $0.25$ to have repeating $0$ after the $5$.

Comment: It is not possible for the ratio of two rational numbers to be a "non-terminating, non-repeating decimal." Is there a mistake in how the question is written?

Comment: If x and y are rational then it $x/y$ will never be non-repeating non-terminating.  Ever.

Comment: If $x$ is rational then $x = m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers.  If $y$ is rational then $y = p/q$ where $p, q$ are integers.  So $x/y = mq/np$ where $mq$ and $mp$ are integers.  So $x/y$ is rational.  So it's decimal expansion terminates or repeats.

Answer (score 4):

First reduce the fraction to lowest terms; that is, assume that $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$. Then $\frac{x}{y}$ terminates (i.e., ends in a string of $0$s or $9$s) if and only if $y=2^r5^s$ for some $r,s \in \Bbb Z^{\geq 0}$.

In general, in base $n = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, the fraction will terminate if and only if $y = p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}$ for some non-negative $b_i$.

If the fraction does not terminate, then it will repeat, since it is rational. Only irrational numbers have decimal expansions that do not terminate or repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x/y$ is rational let $x/y=\pm m/n$ where $m,n$ are positive integers. Now compute the decimal places for $m/n$ in base $10$ (or in any base) by ordinary long division. Eventually every digit that you "bring down" to append to the right-hand side of the remainder will always be a $0.$ There are only $n$ possible remainders $(0,1,...,n-1).$ In the next  $n+1$ steps at least one of these remainders will occur at least twice. Therefore, as soon as a remainder repeats (after all the "bring-downs" are all $0$'s) the pattern will repeat.

I have met university graduates who didn't know this.